# Visual Studio 2012 auto create unit test - WP8 application

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

So, I was also surprised that the "create unit test" is not available from the context menu when right clicking over a method, as opposed to Visual Studio 2010.

The work arounds suggested was to create the unit tests in VS2010 and then import it back to VS2012.

Then i found this post http://dl.my/2013/enable-create-unit-tests-on-visual-studio-2012/
and that indeed worked!

But now, after i click the "create unit test" over a method, the generated class only contains a TestContext property, without the test methods that was chosed in the wizard previously.

This is the generated class:

```
/// <summary>
///This is a test class for XXXTest and is intended
///to contain all XXXTest Unit Tests
///</summary>
[TestClass()]
public class XXXTest
{


    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    /// <summary>
    ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
    ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
    ///</summary>
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    #region Additional test attributes
    // 
    //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
    //
    //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
    //[ClassInitialize()]
    //public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    //{
    //}
    //
    //Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
    //[ClassCleanup()]
    //public static void MyClassCleanup()
    //{
    //}
    //
    //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
    //[TestInitialize()]
    //public void MyTestInitialize()
    //{
    //}
    //
    //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
    //[TestCleanup()]
    //public void MyTestCleanup()
    //{
    //}
    //
    #endregion

}
```

I have searched the web with no results..

Does anybody know what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is not possible to use "Generate Unit Tests..." wizard for Windows Phone projects.

As you try to use the wizard, the following error will be prompted:

```
While trying to generate your tests, the following errors occurred:
You can only add WinMD references to a project targeting Windows 8.0 or higher. To learn how to retarget your project to a different version of Windows, please see the 'Core subgroup' section underneath the 'Windows tab' section in the 'How to: add or remove references by using the Reference Manager' help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh708954(v=vs.110).aspx.
```

The best you can do now is by creating it manually.

Comment: Hey, @DawaLaw you're the post writter!
So why did you write that post if it not possible?? :))

And why the hell did microsoft enabled that feature if it's not working.. weird

Any way, i really have a lot of methods, so i'm trying to migrate the code to VS2010 and generate the unit tests there..

But i'm having trouble importing the unit test projects back to VS2012. many conflicts between DLL's and so..

Worst case i will do it manually.

Comment: Hi @Erez, it is possible to generate unit tests with Windows Forms, Console, and Web Projects. However, I did not test on Windows Phone projects until you posted this questions. After an hour of research, regardless what method I try it will not work. Actually Microsoft disabled this feature and it was posted [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/08/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-11-beta-unit-testing.aspx).
What I can suggest you is to create a class library project, transfer your methods/classes into that project, generate unit test and change the reference.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. 

Gonna go old school on this one.. first time that i'm doing unit testing, so it's probably for the best :)